# Cannot remote debug Azure AppService "unable to find a process called w3wp"

Tags: azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2019, remote-debugging

I have freshly deployed my ASP.NET web application (dotnet 5) to an azure AppService

It is bare-bones in the fact that there's no WebAPI controllers, no routing, no MVC views. It has a simple middleware class that does some request/response trickery to essentially perform work as a reverse proxy.

Everything is actually working pretty well, but I cannot do remote debugging on this site.
I've tried to deploy it as both 'portable' and as 'x86', but get the same result. This is the error message where xxxxxx is my app service name.

> Unable to find a process called w3wp with arguments "xxxxxxx. The process may still be starting, please try again.

[image: remote-debugging-screenshot]

Comment: What is the Visual Studio version you are using ?

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT - VS 2019 - Version 16.11.9 - updated a couple of days ago

Comment: - In Visual studio 2019=> Go to Debug tab => Click on Attach process => In Connection Target paste your site url without htttp like([myappservice.azurewebsites.net](http://myappservice.azurewebsites.net/))  
=> Hit the Refresh button => Add your app service credentials username and password=> A list of process will be shown to you just click on the **w3wp.exe** process => Symbols and required will be loaded and debugger will be attached ,now you can debug .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure Remote Debugging is enabled in Azure Portal.
  Go to Azure Portal =>Your App Service =>Configuration => Select General settings.

[image]

- Change the Configuration option to ***Debug***

[image]

- I got the same issue when I Attach debugger from Hosting menu.
- Instead of ***"Attach Debugger",*** use ***Attach process*** from the VS debug menu.
- Place breakpoint in any of your form. As I am using the basic application ,I have placed in Index.cshtml.cs.
- Copy the Credentials from the Azure Portal.

[image]

- VS 2019=> Go to Debug tab => Attach process => In Connection Target paste your site url without htttp like([myappservice.azurewebsites.net](http://myappservice.azurewebsites.net/))
  =>Refresh button =>  add your app service credentials username and password=> A list of process will be shown to you just click on the w3wp.exe process => Select Show Processes from all users.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Holy macaroni! This was way more difficult than it should've been. I was doing remote debugging successfully a year or so ago with my .NET Framework 4.7 WebAPI - Microsoft really broke this IMHO. Thank you for the detailed explanation. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Easy version of debugging works in VS 2022.In some versions it has to be done in this way :)